# Describing how to value an item or thing

Tags: word-choice

Sorry for another one word request or whatever but it isn't just one word I am looking for, and it also is a bit more of a challenge as I am not looking for a word that *best* describes how to describe the act of placing value on an item using the English language, but yet a word or word combination that is most easily understood by a vast majority of people on how to place value on an item.

The phrase I am using it in is along the lines of -

'Buy, sell, and valuate your assets'

And the specific word I am looking to replace is valuate - I don't feel that the vast majority of visitors to my site will understand what it means to valuate and am looking for a great synonym **that most people feel is best understood** therefore I know the three most common synonyms (estimate, assess, and appraise) but I am looking for what the community feels is the most commonly understood answer.

Comment: I would appreciate if you would post that as an answer to see if the community agrees with you on that one : )

Comment: I think all three of these are equally good, but I think 'value' is the clearest choice in terms of second language readers (if that's even a consideration). Also, 'assess your assets' seems a bit clumsy, unless you want alliteration for effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**"appraise"** is the best option. It's widely understood and synonymous with valuate.

> "Buy, sell, and appraise your assets."

Answer (score 2):

You can consider ***[value](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/value)***, it is a common word in finance and it is understandable.

(It also covers all three words that you listed: estimate, assess, and appraise)

> [value:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/value) to calculate or reckon the monetary value of; give a specified material or financial value to; assess; appraise: *to value their assets.*
>
> [value:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/value) to determine or estimate the worth or value of; appraise.
>
> ---
>
> *Buy, sell, and value your assets*

---

You can consider ***[rate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rate)*** also if there are different rating systems than just estimating the monetary value.

> Assign a standard or value to (something) according to a particular scale

---

Flater's comment:

> To be more clear: If you want to know which of your assets is the most valuable, you're rating them. If you want an idea of their combined worth, you're valuing them.
>
> Rate describes a more comparative intent (you're measuring value specifically in comparison to others). If you value something, you're not inherently looking to compare it. So I guess its application depends on the intention of the measured value.

Comment: Consider rate in the context shown above - 'Buy, sell, or rate your assets' - does the community feel this is the best way to describe the action?

Comment: @PWKad: rate describes a more comparative intent (you're measuring value specifically in comparison to others). If you value something, you're not inherently looking to compare it. So I guess its application depends on the intention of the measured value.

Comment: To be more clear: If you want to know which of your assets is the most valuable, you're rating them. If you want an idea of their combined worth, you're valuing them. At least, that's my interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider *size up*.

> 'Buy, sell, and [size up](http://seekingalpha.com/article/38507-four-priorities-using-socrates-for-csk-autos-new-ceo) your assets"
>
> **size up**: to form an estimate of; appraise

Answer (score 0):

I believe that appraise is a good word.  But **assess** is a better word here.

> to carefully consider a situation, person, or problem in order to make
>   a judgment more...
>
> to calculate what something costs or is worth

Appraise to me sounds like what someone would do when the are an uninterested party giving an estimate.  To assess something would be telling you what you think of it, and then possibly making an offer or give advice.

Comment: One gets an asset appraised in order to *more accurately assess* its monetary value. While assess works, I think appraise is a better choice in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know  the context in which to want to your sentence, but for a word that can be easily understood you may use:

[To price](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Price), meaning:  to ascertain or discover the price of. Price can be used to indicate also the value or worth of something.

Comment: I always assumed pricing was used in the context of having intent to sell it (and the freedom to choose at which price you sell it). In OP's example, selling is already another mentioned option. But I'm not sure whether that leads to it being an implicit tautology or not.